# opencv - how to find center of circular test pattern?

Tags: opencv

Does anybody have a suggestion as to how to find the center point of an image such as the following in OpenCV:

[image]

Please note that the center of the test pattern is NOT at the center of the image, and could vary substantially from one image of the test pattern to the next for various reasons.

At first I did not think this would be very difficult but I'm having a hard time getting ideas started.  Sorry if this is an easy one and I'm missing something obvious.  Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Look for lines, maybe a [Hough line transform](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/hough_lines/hough_lines.html), and then find their common intersection point.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but in this image for example, HoughLines or HoughLinesP would give 72 lines, is there a way mathematically to find the closest approximation of the intersection of 72 lines?  The intersection point of the 72 lines would be very close but not exactly the same is the difficulty.

Comment: Every combination of two lines will have an intersection point.   A simple approximation would be to take the average of those intersection points.  Another method would be to assign each intersection point to a square on a grid and select the square with the most points in it.

Comment: Every 2 combinations will be quite computationally complex...

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I think I'll try the following: 1) Call HoughLinesP() 2) Find the intersection of the first two lines, then the next two, etc, resulting in 36 intersection points, then average those.  I would have to throw one line out if an odd number of lines was used but for my purposes here the accuracy should be more than sufficient.  I'll most likely post my response in code when I get it working.

Comment: See my answer below, the Blur step effectively works as the averaging function there. It should be immune from [moiré](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moiré_pattern) issues too. (in your image the under-sampling that made the grey dot in the middle was *prior* to the sampling that made the digital file)

Answer (score 5):

[Blur](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html?highlight=gaussianblur#void%20GaussianBlur(InputArray%20src,%20OutputArray%20dst,%20Size%20ksize,%20double%20sigmaX,%20double%20sigmaY,%20int%20borderType)):

[image]

[Binary Threshold](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_thresholding/py_thresholding.html):

[image]

Then [***Hough circles***](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/hough_circle/hough_circle.html)

---

If you're set on using a [Houghlines](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/hough_lines/hough_lines.html), I'd use [Least Squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_squares) to find an optima that is the closest solution to all the lines.

It just needs the right formulation, which I do not present here. I suspect it would be more computationally efficient than finding the mean of all combinations...